# How do I reuse an existing service principal to push images to Azure Container Registry?

Tags: docker, azure-devops

We have an issue with v2 of the Docker pipeline task and the Docker Registry service connection. The Docker v2 pipeline task seems to require a Docker Registry service connection. When setting up the connection for an ACR it tries to generate a new service principal. Unfortunately, this just doesn't work for us because our corporate policy restricts us from doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `Others` authentication type to reuse my service principal credentials, instead of creating a new one using the `Azure Container Registry` authentication type.

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3fXO.png)

Where I've set

1. Docker Registry: My ACR URL (https://myacr.azurecr.io)
2. Docker ID: Service Principal ID
3. Password: Service Principal Key

Ensure that the service principal you're using has required permissions on your ACR.